# How to create a json file inside the resource folder in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, fileoutputstream

I want to write into a json file inside the resource folder of springboot. So I wanted to check, how to create a file and insert data. If file exists after creation then add the data into file, else create file and add data.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();    
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new      
    File(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/Response.json").toString()));    
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new 
    OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);    
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);    
try { 
     for(list){} 
     string result="user Should be active user";  
     writer.write(String.valueOf(result)); 
     writer.close();
} catch{}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, If you're using docker or any container to deploy the apps, just let the code to write on the root folder (home where app.jar deployed), coz in the runtime actually the metadata will not accessible since it already bundled on the jar by spring-boot.